# Convert str data to proper format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have a Input like

```
"3-August 202212.00 PM"
```

Expected output :

```
"03-08-2022,12:00:00PM"
```

Any suggestion recommended. I tried to convert to datetime and after strftime.But it not works due to 202212.00 pm.

Final output type will be str not datetime

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the "it" thats not working"? [ask]

Answer (score 6):

`strftime` works, you just need to use the correct [directives](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) in both directions:

```py
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('3-August 202212.00 PM',
                         '%d-%B %Y%I.%M %p')

print(date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y,%I:%M:%S%p'))
```

outputs

```
'03-08-2022,12:00:00PM'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use datetime to get the result in 2 steps:

1. convert `str` to `datetime` format
2. convert `datetime` object to `str` in the new format

```
import datetime as dt
x = "3-August 202212.00 PM"

x = dt.datetime.strptime(x, "%d-%B %Y%I.%M %p").strftime("%d-%m-%Y,%I:%M:%S %p")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
03-08-2022,12:00:00 PM
```

If you have a `pd.DataFrame` with given strings, you can do as follows:
Supposed we have a `DataFrame` with the following output:

```
import pandas as pd
y = pd.DataFrame(["3-August 202212.00 PM", "3-March 202104.00 AM", "6-July 202202.00 PM", "23-December 202009.00 AM", "27-May 201806.50 PM"], columns=['Date'])
```

```
>>> y
    Date
0   3-August 202212.00 PM
1   3-March 202104.00 AM
2   6-July 202202.00 PM
3   23-December 202009.00 AM
4   27-May 201806.50 PM
```

Use:

```
y = pd.to_datetime(y.Date, format='%d-%B %Y%I.%M %p', errors='coerce').apply(lambda x: x.strftime("%d-%m-%Y,%I:%M:%S %p"))
print(type(y))
# pd.to_datetime returns type pandas.core.series.Series so y need to be converted back to dataframe
y = pd.DataFrame(y)
```

will give a result:

```
>>> y
    Date
0   03-08-2022,12:00:00 PM
1   03-03-2021,04:00:00 AM
2   06-07-2022,02:00:00 PM
3   23-12-2020,09:00:00 AM
4   27-05-2018,06:50:00 PM
```

**Note:**
Need to be careful when converting hour. in this case you will want to use `%I` instead of `%H` since:

`%I` : Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

`%H` : Hour (24-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.

Comment: But here i face only one problem if i will give input '3-August 202202.00 PM' output will be 02:00:00 AM.(i think 24 hrs format problem) how can we address this

Comment: You can change `%H` to `%I` since `%I` is used in 12-hour format.